# What is the role of the `load()` method in the collection class?

Tags: magento2, collection, product-collection

In `Magento\Framework\Data\Collection` there is a method `getFirstItem` which calls `$this->load()`

```
public function getFirstItem()
{
    $this->load();
...}
```

`load` method from the same class:

```
/**
 * Load data
 *
 * @param bool $printQuery
 * @param bool $logQuery
 * @return $this
 */
public function load($printQuery = false, $logQuery = false)
{
    return $this->loadData($printQuery, $logQuery);
}
```

`loadData` from this class:

```
/**
 * Load data
 *
 * @param bool $printQuery
 * @param bool $logQuery
 * @return $this
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
 */
public function loadData($printQuery = false, $logQuery = false)
{
    return $this;
}
```

it seems that `load` does nothing useful but when I comment it out it affects execution of code. How does calling this method trigger any action?

Are there any magic php methods that are executed on `return $this;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In collection, **load()** method does the below things as per my understanding that could help you.

1. **_beforeLoad** and **_afterLoad** event fires.
2. **order** and **limit** set in the query.
3. Build the **collection** into **object** and return

For more you can check the class **Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb** which extends the Magento\Framework\Data\Collection

Comment: thanks. Looking at the class `Magento\Framework\Data\Collection`, it doesn't implement `AbstractDb` in M2.2.3. Maybe I'm missing something but even if it did how could it run methods from the abstract parent class if they're already defined in the Collection/child class?

Comment: No, Actually class AbstractDb extends the class Magento\Framework\Data\Collection so here is AbstractDb is child class.  In general, every collection class extents \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection which extends Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb where load() method functionality written.